# SSD changes mount point during partitioning

Tags: partition, disk, gparted

I booted up my computer after a week without using it and I was greeted with a MS-DOS prompt saying that my disk had read errors instead of booting up Windows.
Fed up with the latter OS, I decided to format my SSD and install Pop!_OS.
However, when partitioning my drive, I have the following log :

```
GParted 1.2.0

configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.4

========================================
...
elapsed by me : description of my other drives
mounted on /dev/sda and /dev/sdb
...
========================================
Device: /dev/sdc
Model:  ATA KINGSTON SA400S3
Serial: 50026B73811B943A
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  937703088
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  1838633
 
Partition table:    msdos
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point

========================================
Device: /dev/sdd
Model:  Generic Flash Disk
Serial: 
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  15728640
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  30840
 
Partition table:    none
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdd    Unpartitioned   0   15728639            iso9660 Pop_OS 21.10 amd64 Nvidia   

========================================
Create Primary Partition #1 (ext4, 447.13 GiB) on /dev/sdc  00:00:19    ( ERROR )
        
create empty partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sdc1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 937701375
size: 937699328 (447.13 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdc1  00:00:19    ( ERROR )
        
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 274877906944  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 512.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 480101531648  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 480101990400  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 8.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 480102047744  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdc  00:00:18    ( ERROR )
        
libparted messages    ( ERROR )
        
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdc: Input/output error
```

After checking my Disks menu, I can see the KINGSTON SA400S3 drive mounted on /dev/sde.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: your disk is probably dead. Check log (`journalctl -r`), you'll probably see some I/O errors there too. You can also try running [SMART](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/S.M.A.R.T.) test to check the disk health (GNOME Disks can do that too).

It is also possible the disk itself is OK and this is just a bad cable/connection. Disk that disappeared and reappeared after being disconnected and reconnected would explain the change from `/dev/sdc` to `/dev/sde` (these are not mount points, but device files representing the raw block device assigned by kernel when the block device (disk) appears).

Comment: Greetings, and thanks for your answer!
I provided further information regarding your answer below

Answer (score 0):

and thanks for your answer!
`journalctl -r` indeed contains I/O errors, such as :

```
Apr 02 17:34:27 pop-os kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210930/psargs-330)

Apr 02 17:34:55 pop-os kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sde, logical block 0, async page read
Apr 02 17:34:55 pop-os kernel: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 02 17:34:55 pop-os kernel: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
```

However, my disk passes the SMART!

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Phison Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37480G
Serial Number:    50026B73811B943A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 3811b943a
Firmware Version: S3H01103
User Capacity:    480,103,981,056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Apr  2 17:52:45 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       374
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       71
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
167 Write_Protect_Mode      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 SATA_Phy_Error_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9965
169 Bad_Block_Rate          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
170 Bad_Blk_Ct_Erl/Lat      0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 MaxAvgErase_Ct          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   026   026   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 16/26)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 CRC_Error_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9965
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100
233 Flash_Writes_GiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       528
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       994
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       462
244 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7
245 Max_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21
246 Total_Erase_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3891

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       374         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%       372         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%       372         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%       372         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       370         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       370         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

I will try to change the SATA port in which my drive is connected & the cable, and if that does not change anything, I guess it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is now solved!
The cause of my problems has been found : my SATA port seems to be faulty. I switched from SATA_5 to SATA_6 and I managed to partition my drive successfully!